# clearcanvas if file is a dicomfile

Tags: dicom, clearcanvas

How to check if file is a dicomfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Clearcanvas `DicomFile.Load` method throws an exception if the file is not a valid dicomfile. On the [clearcanvas forums](http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/Community/Forums/tabid/69/aff/3/aft/13277/afv/topic/Default.aspx). I've found a similar topic. They are saying that if you ónly want to see if the file is a valid dicom file, you can add the following parameter to the `DicomFile.Load` method: `DicomReadOptions.DoNotStorePixelDataInDataSet`, this will speed it up a bit.